# angularjs html 5 mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat8

I am using angularjs with java tomcat 
i have an application that her base url is myapplication/app/index.html
Everything works great when i use the # in the url
When i try to switch to html 5 mode it goes crazy 
i added the base url meta tag but with no luck in every option  i can 
with the entire path or with out `<base href="index.html" />`
and set up the configuration for the app as `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
nothing seems to help me any ideas ?

app code :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
```

or

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

for the code base i tried every thing from

```
<base href="/" />
```

to

```
<base href="myappname/pathtofiles/" />
```

Comment: your base href should be `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Tried it - it doesnt work all the js files and css can't be found

Comment: Can you post some html head code

Comment: you need to share relevant code

Comment: i added some more code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Need that your server always returns index.html. For this purposes you can use, for example, Express server: http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2013/08/05/angularjs-in-html5-mode-with-expressjs/

If you use tomcat, maybe, one of them solutions will be useful for server side rewrites urls (with tomcat often use Apache Rewrites): https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: So you think its a server configuration issue ?

Comment: If you did not configure rewrites urls, you should obviously do this. It don't work without this.

Comment: This link: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode, how I wrote above, explains this.

Comment: What are you using as a development server?

Comment: I use tomcat 8 with spring restful server